# Drag and Drop throws javascript error when developer tools is opened

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, angular

It's only happening in IE im currently working with IE 11 chrome, safari and mozilla works perfectly fine.I have a primeng datatable and i have reorderable columns when im reordering my columns there is no problem it works fine but when i opened f12 developer tools on IE then try to reorder its firing an error

Unexpected call to method or property access

if developer tools is closed it works.What should i do with this strange behaviour?

Comment: Check your emulation settings on your dev tools, you may be emulating an older browser that doesn't have drag and drop support

Comment: It's behaving like that in edge itself.